Emails on Mailchimp aren't uploading my photos
I had made emails on mailchimp, they are looking good on yahoo, but on the gmail and outlook, the images that're in the emails are not loading up. Even the background-which is image, is not loading in gmail and outlook. I tried to resize the images, but it is not working again. Is someone know how to fix this problem?
I tried to resize the images, but it is not working again.
